# Solr server is running but no admin panel

Tags: solr, sitecore

I am trying to get a solr server running to use with Sitecore, but I can't seem to get it to work.

When I start solr (6.6.1) I get the message:

### > bin\solr.cmd -p 8983

> Waiting up to 30 to see Solr running on port 8983
>
> Started Solr server on port 8983. Happy searching!

But when I go to localhost:8983/solr/ I get an empty page or some messages about not being able to connect (differs from each browser).

When I do a status it says that the server is running and some information about the usage so this seems fine.

But when I do a healthcheck on the server I get a lot of warnings saying:

```
WARN  - 2018-02-27 09:48:27.768; org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x0 for server BBLP-JSCHOOT.colo.betabit.nl/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8983, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Packet len352518912 is out of range!
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket.readLength(ClientCnxnSocket.java:112)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:79)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
WARN  - 2018-02-27 09:48:28.240; org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x0 for server pso/127.0.0.1:8983, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

and after some of these I get:

> ERROR: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper localhost:8983 within 10000 ms

Anyone has any idea what can cause this? Seems that something is wrong with zookeeper but I can't quite figure out what that is.

Comment: Seems like you've configured Zookeeper to run on port 8983 / Solr to use zookeeper on port 8983 - the complaint from Zookeeper is that "Eeeeh, this isn't a zookeeper connection", as it gets served HTML (or something similar) when trying to start up.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for your comment but how do I get it to work then?

Comment: Well, it indicates that you've configured something wrong - so what have you done about configuration? How are you starting Solr - exactly what parameters? Any environment settings? Are you using the embedded zookeeper or an external one?